# xdotool commands run one by one

Tags: bash, xdotool

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
  terminator
  xdotool type 'myalias'
  xdotool key Return
  xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
  xdotool type 'cd ~/git/apps/myapp/client && gulp'
  xdotool key Return
}

foo
```

I run this script from a key shortcut.

It opens the terminal, but only executes the following commands after I close the terminal

Any idea around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands after `terminator` will not execute until `terminator` exits, so you will have to send it to the background:

```
terminator &
```

This will allow the script to continue with the other steps immediately after starting terminator (which may be too soon), so try:

```
...
terminator &
sleep 3
xdotool type 'myalias'
...
```

Comment: sleep 1 was enough :)